# connect to kdb+ DB from a .q file

Tags: kdb

I am using `kdb+` & `nodeJS`. I need to send queries from node to the db.

when I cd to the "db" directory and type `q db` I have `candles` set.
I created inside "db" folder a file called `startServer.q`:

```
\p 8080  
h:hopen `:localhost:8080:user:pass
```

When I run `startServer.q` it opens but it seems that the `candles` variable is not set.
How can I access this table from that file? didn't find anything on the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you `cd` into the `db` folder and run `q startServer.q` the variable candles will not be set because it has not been loaded in, you just need to do:

```
q) \l /path/to/db
```

after you do `q startServer.q` and it will load in the table(s) in the `db` folder.

It would be a good idea to have `startServer.q` and `db` folder at the same level in your directory, i.e.

```
.
├── parent-directory
│   ├── db
│   └── startServer.q
```

then you could add the line

```
system["l db"];
```

to your `startServer.q` file and it would load in when you do `q startServer.q`.

Comment: Thanks! that worked. Can you also explain why the second approach is better?

Comment: Yes, no problem. Your `db` folder is your database of tables (I'm assuming) and `startServer.q` is not a table so it would be better to not have this file in that directory.